# WebJobs in multiple deployments slots and StorageAccounts

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-account

I am trying web-jobs using deployment slots (dev, qa, prod). It seems like each slot seems to need its own storage-account, as when I try and use the same storage account, the jobs (its a time based job) runs only in one of the slots. In all the others, the job never fires.

I have tried provisioning another storage account and when I set the connections strings (AzureWebJobsDashboard, AzureWebJobsStorage) in QA, the jobs begin firing (which seems to prove that I need multiple storage accounts). But I dont want to have to pay for 3 separate storage accounts, where the dev and qa will not be used all that much. Is there any setting that can be used that will allow one storage-account to be used by different slots?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a different storage account, but you do need to set a different `HostId` on the `JobHostConfiguration` object. You can use an environment variable to read it, and then set that to different values as a Slot App Setting in each of your slots.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/56 for related info.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this on the Configuration of the Azure Function as a slot setting? or can it only be done from the C# source code? I googled for about 1 hour, cant find the example